# Can I change the maxActive property of a org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dynamically?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have a webapp running with a Groovy console attached.

I have the following bean configured via XML:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClass}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="${db.validationQuery}" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000" />
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="8" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="logAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="60"/>

        <!--connection pooling props -->
        <property name="maxActive" value="${db.maxActive}"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${db.maxIdle}"/>
        <property name="maxAge" value="${db.maxAge}"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="${db.maxWait}"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="${db.initialSize}"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="${db.minIdle}"/>
    </bean>
```

Via the Groovy console, I can easily call:

```
appCtx.getBean("dataSource").setMaxActive(someNumber);
```

where `appCtx` is my Spring application context.

My question is, will this *actually* change the connection pool behaviour. All the links I've found seem to focus on initial configuration. I'm trying to modify configuration after the pool is established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On inspection of `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool`, it looks like it is checking the `maxActive` property when fetching a connection from the pool.

So I can't say I know from experience, but it looks like it should work to set this value at Runtime.

Comment: This one should probably receive some actually runtime verification. It does look like the code could be expecting that the maxActive property won't be changed at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find anything in the documentation either, but from looking at the implementation I'm pretty sure it's not intended to support modification after initialization for the following reasons:

- There is no code written to handle updates to that property, except simply to update the field value.
- There is a lot of code that does verification of that property in org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(). None of that code is run if the property is set later.
- The init() method also allocates at least one queue with a fixed capacity that is never updated elsewhere in the code.